If the target category has all copowers then all right Kan extensions that exist are pointwise
$\def\C{\mathsf{C}}
\def\D{\mathsf{D}}
\def\E{\mathsf{E}}
\def\ran{\operatorname{Ran}}
\def\lan{\operatorname{Lan}}$In [Riehl, Sect. 6.3], we find:

Exercise 6.3.i. Prove that if $\mathsf{E}$ is locally small and has all small copowers, then all right Kan extensions with codomain $\mathsf{E}$ are pointwise right Kan extensions. Dually, if $\mathsf{E}$ is locally small and has all small powers, then all left Kan extensions with codomain $\mathsf{E}$ are pointwise.

Where:

By “$\E$ has all small copowers” I interpret that $\coprod_Se$ exists for all sets $S$ and all objects $e\in\E$ (and dually for small powers).

A right Kan extension of a functor $F:\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{E}$ along $K:\C\to\D$ is said to be pointwise if it is preserved by the covariant representable functor $\E(e,-)$, for all $e\in\E$ (dually, one defines pointwise for left Kan extensions). Equivalently, a right Kan extension is pointwise if and only if $\lim(d\downarrow K \xrightarrow{\Pi_d}\C\xrightarrow{F}\E)$ exists for each $d\in\D$ and this limit is isomorphic to $\ran_KF(d)$ [Riehl, Theorem 6.2.1].


I am a little bit clueless about how to tackle the exercise. Does anyone have any hints?

References
[Riehl] E. Riehl, Category Theory in Context

There is a funny duality: you can construct right Kan extensions using small powers (and taking an end) but you can preserve them by taking copowers.

$\def\E{\mathsf{E}}$It was easier than I expected. The functor $\E(e,-):\E\to\mathsf{Set}$ is right adjoint to $S\mapsto S\cdot a=\coprod_Sa$, the copower. Thus $\E(e,-)$ preserves all right Kan extensions [Riehl, 6.3.2].
